# "Having that said" or "Having said that"?

Tags: sentence-construction, word-order

Let 'X' and 'Y' denote two different sentences. Then which of the following formulations is correct?

> X. Having that said, Y.
>
> X. Having said that, Y.

My personal reading experience is telling me the former one is right but later one also looks fine to me.
Are both of these correct?

Comment: I invariably see the second - "Having said that, ..."

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The phrase is [*having said that*](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/having-said-that?a=british).  It's a pre-formed phrase in the lexicon, and you should learn it as a single unit.

In the [Corpus of Contemporary American English (COCA)](https://corpus.byu.edu/coca/), I searched for both phrases using the query `. having said|that said|that ,`.  I found 367 results for *having said that* at the beginning of a sentence, and 0 results for *having that said*.  Likewise, in the [British National Corpus (BNC)](https://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/), I found 111 results for for the former and 0 results for the latter.

These results show that people don't really reverse the word order – or if they do, that they don't do it very often.  In this case, *said* is a past participle in a perfect construction, not a participial adjective derived from a verb form, so it uses the standard word order with the object following the verb.  The other word order isn't *ungrammatical*, but I recommend you stick to the usual way of saying it.